# The meaning of urlSession.dataTaskWithRequest(request)

Tags: swift, rest, get

When I read the book about swift in the Network Development chapter, I met some code which I cannot understand. The code is as follows:

```
let sessionTask = urlSession.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            (data, response, error) in

            handler(response, data)
            }
```

the prototype of this function in swift is：

```
public func dataTaskWithRequest(request: NSURLRequest, completionHandler: (NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void) -> NSURLSessionDataTask
```

As you can see, the prototype has 2 parameters, one is request, another is completionHandler. But in the above code, it also has one parameter. And also I cannot understand the code in the curly braces, where do the 3 variable data, response, error come from? I cannot find any definition of the 3 variables. Who can help me understand the code, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called a trailing closure, it's a cleaner way of passing a function to another function if that function is the last argument. The same code can be written as:

```
let sessionTask = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let request = NSURLRequest()
sessionTask.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

})
```

> If you need to pass a closure expression to a function as the function’s final argument and the closure expression is long, it can be useful to write it as a trailing closure instead. A trailing closure is a closure expression that is written outside of (and after) the parentheses of the function call it supports

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102

```
func aFunction(callback: (done: Bool) -> Void) {
  let finished = true
  callback(done: finished)
}

aFunction { (done) -> Void in
  print("we are done \(done)")
}
```

Comment: ok, now I understand the syntax of the trailing closure, but where are the 3 variables data, response, error from, do they come from the response of the  http request please?

Comment: The 3 variables data, response, error are passed in from NSURLSession's dataTaskWithRequest method.

Comment: I mean when we pass a parameter to a function, we should first define it, for example:

Comment: Yes you are right, and the 3 variables data, response, error were defined inside the implementation of NSURLSession's dataTaskWithRequest method. By the way I can see your example.

Comment: I mean when we pass a parameter to a function, we should first define it, for example: var a = 90 if we pass a to the function defined as func func1(a:int)->int, then we should call like func1(a). As you can see, we defined variable a before we pass it in the func1. Similarly, we call the completionHandler like {(data, response, error) in

            handler(response, data)} . But we do not define the 3 parameters, why is that?

Comment: ok, I think I have already understood the code, thanks for your explanation.